# Microsoft Blend - drawing polygons

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, blend

I recently downloaded trial version of Microsoft Expression Blend and I can't figure out how I can draw polygons. I only found predefined shapes like pentagon,octagon, triangles but I can't find a tool to draw polygon

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Pen tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295231%28Expression.30%29.aspx). See http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc188984.aspx for a video tutorial.

Comment: Using that tool will i be able to use "Make into control" ?

Comment: You can right click and choose make into control, that will create a template that looks like what you have drawn. But if you want to create a shape that resizes in a particular way or allows you to choose number of sides e.t.c you will need to write code to create it instead of using the pen tool.

Answer (score 3):

In Expresion Blend 4:

1. Place a any RegularPolygon shape such as a triangle, pentagon, or Hexagon on your canvas.
2. Go to the Properties Panel and expand the Appearance section.
3. Change the point count to the number of sides you want. 8 for Octagon, etc.